# BPF filtering does not work on raw sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bpf

I want to implement filtering all data on port 22 in tcp data packets
I used the bpf code generated by tcpdump to apply it in the code, but it didn't work

Below is my test code

```
int main()
{
    /* From the example above: tcpdump -d host 127.0.0.1 and  port 22 -i lo */
    struct sock_filter code[] = {
        {0x28, 0, 0, 0x0000000c},
        {0x15, 0, 16, 0x00000800},
        {0x20, 0, 0, 0x0000001a},
        {0x15, 2, 0, 0x7f000001},
        {0x20, 0, 0, 0x0000001e},
        {0x15, 0, 12, 0x7f000001},
        {0x30, 0, 0, 0x00000017},
        {0x15, 2, 0, 0x00000084},
        {0x15, 1, 0, 0x00000006},
        {0x15, 0, 8, 0x00000011},
        {0x28, 0, 0, 0x00000014},
        {0x45, 6, 0, 0x00001fff},
        {0xb1, 0, 0, 0x0000000e},
        {0x48, 0, 0, 0x0000000e},
        {0x15, 2, 0, 0x00000016},
        {0x48, 0, 0, 0x00000010},
        {0x15, 0, 1, 0x00000016},
        {0x6, 0, 0, 0x00040000},
        {0x6, 0, 0, 0x00000000},
    };

    struct sock_fprog bpf = {
        .len    = ARRAY_SIZE(code),
        .filter = code,
    };

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);

    int enable_hdrincl = 1;
    setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &enable_hdrincl, sizeof(enable_hdrincl));

    int ret = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, &bpf, sizeof(bpf));

    char buffer[4096];
    while (1) {
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        ssize_t recv_len = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (recv_len < 0) {
            perror("recv failed");
            close(sock);
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("xxx\r\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I use tcpdump on the command line it filters normally

```bash
lcx@lcx-virtual-machine:/mnt/hgfs/share/tcp_demo/test$ sudo tcpdump  host 127.0.0.1 and  port 22 -i lo
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
10:50:34.761640 IP lcx-virtual-machine.2222 > localhost.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1234, win 65535, length 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it didn't work_?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The packet offsets in the example `sock_filter code` refer to the whole packet including the Ethernet header; since the socket in the test program is set up to include only the IP header, the offsets do not match and the filter fails. In order to read the whole Ethernet packet and be able to use the given filter, you can use

```
    int sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));
```

and you can drop `IP_HDRINCL` therewith.

If for some strange reason you don't want to read the Ethernet header, you have to adjust the offsets in the BPF code - the numbers in brackets in its  human readable form:

```
# tcpdump -d host 127.0.0.1 and  port 22 -i lo
(000) ldh      [12]
(001) jeq      #0x800           jt 2    jf 18
(002) ld       [26]
(003) jeq      #0x7f000001      jt 6    jf 4
(004) ld       [30]
(005) jeq      #0x7f000001      jt 6    jf 18
(006) ldb      [23]
(007) jeq      #0x84            jt 10   jf 8
(008) jeq      #0x6             jt 10   jf 9
(009) jeq      #0x11            jt 10   jf 18
(010) ldh      [20]
(011) jset     #0x1fff          jt 18   jf 12
(012) ldxb     4*([14]&0xf)
(013) ldh      [x + 14]
(014) jeq      #0x16            jt 17   jf 15
(015) ldh      [x + 16]
(016) jeq      #0x16            jt 17   jf 18
(017) ret      #262144
(018) ret      #0
```

- and disable the first two instructions which check the Ethernet Protocol ID; this results in the code:

```
        {},
        {},
        {0x20, 0, 0, 0x0000000c},   // 26 -> 12
        {0x15, 2, 0, 0x7f000001},
        {0x20, 0, 0, 0x00000010},   // 30 -> 16
        {0x15, 0, 12, 0x7f000001},
        {0x30, 0, 0, 0x00000009},   // 23 -> 9
        {0x15, 2, 0, 0x00000084},
        {0x15, 1, 0, 0x00000006},
        {0x15, 0, 8, 0x00000011},
        {0x28, 0, 0, 0x00000006},   // 20 -> 6
        {0x45, 6, 0, 0x00001fff},
        {0xb1, 0, 0, 0x00000000},   // 14 -> 0
        {0x48, 0, 0, 0x00000000},   // 14 -> 0
        {0x15, 2, 0, 0x00000016},
        {0x48, 0, 0, 0x00000002},   // 16 -> 2
        {0x15, 0, 1, 0x00000016},
        {0x6, 0, 0, 0x00040000},
        {0x6, 0, 0, 0x00000000},
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your prompt to make changes, it is true that the message can be filtered, but the data packet accepted in this way contains the MAC header, my intention is to only receive the IP header and the TCP header, please ask me how to modify this BPF CODE, I do not understand BPF CODE, my project only needs to use him once, so I have no idea to study him in depth, please ask you to answer for me

Comment: I don't understand why you resist reading the additional 14 bytes of the Ethernet header, but I amended my answer with an alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer again, because my sock is ‘socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)’, so what I will get is ip-tcp data packet, which has been confirmed, I don't need to filter, next I want to implement ‘bind’ and ‘listen’ functions, which is to listen to the data of a specified port, so I want to use bpf to filter and only get the data packet of the port I bound, so bpf only needs to filter the port.